# Find all narcissistic (armstrong) numbers faster on Java

Tags: java, optimization

Is there more efficient way to do that?
Given number N - find all the narcissistic ( armstrong ) numbers that < N.
Here is my code, but I guess there is more efficient solutions. Also, probably, we could solve it through bit operation?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws  Exception
 {
    long a = System.nanoTime();
    int t [] = getNumbers(4_483_647L);
    long b = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Time totally "+(b-a));
    for(int k: t)
        System.out.print(k+" ");
}
public static int[] getNumbers(long N)
{

    int length=1;
    int porog=10, r=1, s=1;
    double k;
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(i==porog)
        {
            length++;
            porog*=10;
        }
        s = i;
        k=0;
        while(s>0)
        {
            r = s%10;
            k+=Math.pow(r, length);
            if(k>i)break;
            s=s/10;
        }
        if((int)k==i)
            list.add(i);
    }
   int[] result  = new int[list.size()];
    int i=0;
    for(int n: list)
    {
        result[i] = n;
        i++;
    }

    return result;  }  }
```

Comment: ok may be its not good place to ask this question. But I was interested in Java solutions.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number says There are only 88 narcissistic numbers in base 10, problem for such a case will be finding them all than speed or efficiency (in my opinion, since solution set is **finite** for infinite numbers

Comment: You can probably shave off some cycles by precalculating the powers each time your increase `length`. For each `length`, you'll only need the powers i^length for i=0..9, but you'll need them an increasing number of times. Also, look at `Collections.toArray()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some observations:

- If your initial maximum is a `long`, your results should be `long` types, too, just in case (`int` works for you as the narcissistic numbers are far apart)
- If you change your return type to be a "big" `Long`, you can use `Collections.toArray()` to repack the results to an array...
- ...although really, you should just return the linked list...
- You don't need to keep recalculating powers. For each decade in the outer loop, you only ever need i^j, where i=0..9 and j is the number of digits in the current decade
- In fact, you don't need `Math.pow()` at all, as you can just use multiplication at each decade

Applying my ideas from my comment above and also changing the method signature, you get something that runs about 30 times faster:

```
public static Long[] getNumbers(long N) {
    int porog = 10;
    LinkedList<Long> list = new LinkedList<>();
    // initial powers for the number 0-9
    long[] powers = { 0l, 1l, 2l, 3l, 4l, 5l, 6l, 7l, 8l, 9l };

    for (long i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (i == porog) {
            porog *= 10;
            // calculate i^length
            for (int pi = 1; pi < 10; pi++) {
                powers[pi] *= pi;
            }
        }
        long s = i;
        long k = 0;
        while (s > 0) {
            int r = (int)(s % 10);
            k += powers[r];
            if (k > i)
                break;
            s /= 10;
        }

        if (k == i)
            list.add(i);
    }

    return list.toArray(new Long[]{});
}
```

Comment: Please tell me any good book where i can learn this kind magic. outstanding. But seriously, please tell me about those resources.

Comment: I came up with the idea of precalculating the powers by realizing that the powers are reused so much. That's the core of optimizing an algorithm: shaving off repeated operations. I then realized that since you're progressing through the numbers, you don't even *need* Math.pow, as each time you need i^(j+1)=i^j*i.

But to answer your question, I probably learned optimization techniques mostly from college books like Introduction to Algorithms: https://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844. Read these books as "learn to optimize" rather than a recipe book.

Answer (score 2):

From [Rosetta Code blog](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Narcissistic_decimal_number#Java) (not my own code)

```
public static boolean isNarc(long x){
    if(x < 0) return false;

    String xStr = Long.toString(x);
    int m = xStr.length();
    long sum = 0;

    for(char c : xStr.toCharArray()){
        sum += Math.pow(Character.digit(c, 10), m);
    }
    return sum == x;
}
```

Comment: but character digit is new to me=) very interesting

Answer (score 1):

A major optimisation is to **not**  examine all the numbers in range `1..N` . Have a look [here](https://github.com/sorokod/Armstrong).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to generate Armstrong Numbers quite efficient. For example, all integers can be generated within 10-15 ms.

We may note that for each multi-set of digits, like `[1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 7]` there is only one sum of powers, which in its turn may either be or be not represented by the digits from set. In the example `1^7 + 1^7 + 2^7 + 4^7 + 5^7 + 7^7 + 7^7 = 1741725`, which can be represented by the digits and thus is an Armstrong number.

We may build an algorithm basing on this consideration.

1. For each number length from `1 to N`
2. Generate all possible multi-sets of `N` digits
3. For each multi-set calculate sum of `digits^N`
4. Check if it's possible to represent the number we got on step 4 with
   the digits from the multi-set
5. If so - add the number to the result list

The number of cases calculated for each length `N` is equal to the number of combinations `(N + 9, 9) = (N+9)!/(9!N!)`. Thus for all `Ns` less than 10 we will generate only 92,377 multi-sets. For `N<20`: 20,030,009.

Please see [GitHub](https://github.com/shamily/ArmstrongNumbers) for the description of a few approaches, along with some benchmarking and the Java code. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a professional coder, just self taught with no work experience, so I apologize if my code is bit sloppy.

I took dovetalk's solution and 1) wrote it myself so to better understand it b) made some adjustments that improved the run time considerably for large numbers. I hope this helps anyone else looking for help with this problem:

```
 public static long[] getNumbers(long N) {

        long tempII = N;
        LinkedHashSet<Long> narcNums = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        long tempResult;
        long digitLengthTemp = 10;
        long tempI;
        long[] powers = {0l, 1l, 2l, 3l, 4l, 5l, 6l, 7l, 8l, 9l};

        for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (i == digitLengthTemp) {
                digitLengthTemp *= 10;
                for (short x = 2; x < powers.length; x++) powers[x] *= x;
            }
            //set value of top digits of numbers past first 3 to a remedial value
            tempI = i;
            long remedialValue = 0;
            tempI /= 10; tempI /= 10; tempI /= 10;

            while (tempI > 0) {
                short index = (short) (tempI % 10);
                remedialValue += powers[index];
                tempI /= 10;
            }
            //only passes 1000 at a time to this loop and adds each result to remedial top half
            for (int j = 0; j < (tempII > 1000 ? 1000 : tempII); j++) {
                //sets digit length and increases the values in array
                if (i == 0 && j == digitLengthTemp) {
                    digitLengthTemp *= 10;
                    for (short x = 2; x < powers.length; x++) powers[x] *= x;

                }
                //resets temp results
                tempResult = remedialValue;
                tempI = j;


                //gets the sum of each (digit^numberLength) of number passed to it
                while (tempI > 0) {
                    if (tempResult > i + j) break;
                    short index = (short) (tempI % 10);
                    tempResult += powers[index];
                    tempI /= 10;
                }

                //checks if sum equals original number
                if (i + j == tempResult) narcNums.add(i + j);
            }
            i += 999; // adds to i in increments of 1000
            tempII -= 1000;
        }

        //converts to long array
        long[] results = new long[narcNums.size()];
        short i = 0;
        for (long x : narcNums) {
            results[i++] = x;
        }
        return results;
}
```